# "Mrs. Jones going to New York" vs "Mrs. Jones gone to New York"

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, past-participles, present-participles

I am giving two sentences below. Please get me clear. I am confused.

> 1. Mrs. Jones went to the New York.
> 2. Mr. Smith took up her position. This is the context.

If I join the two sentences above into two sentences using the participle, then which sentence is meaningful or do both of them carry the same meaning?    Sentences with participle are as follows:

a) (With) Mrs. Jones going to New york, Mr. Smith took up her position.

b) (With) Mrs. Jones gone to New york, Mr. Smith took up her position.

Source:[Present participle or past participle](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/participles)

Comment: They're both grammatical, but they mean different things. Did Mr Smith take up Mrs Jones’ position _before_ she left (perhaps with Mrs Jones helping him become familiar with the job during the last while she was there), or did he only do so _after_ she left?

Comment: I imagine she is actually going to New **Y**ork

Answer (score -1):

When combining two sentences together, the tense muse be the same or equal

For example: I go to work and my brother is being at my company

-The first phrase uses simple present tense and the after one must use the same simple present or equal (present continuous or future tense ... )-

For me the second sentence is better. What do you think?

Comment: No - this is not correct. And in addition to that you have spelling and grammatical mistakes throughout